# Using the User API with Google Cloud Endpoint

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I successfully created a Google Cloud Endpoint backend module for my Android app and I am able to write, read and delete entites.But I have one problem, I want users of my app to be uniquely identified and to store individual entities independent of the other.For example, when `User A` logs in, and saves an entity, it should be independent of what `User B` saves. With each user being able to perform CRUD operations on their independent data in the datastore without affecting the other's. I know this can be possible with the help of the [User class](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/users/User#User%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) from Google's [User's API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/users/#Java_Signing_in_and_out) but I have to clue on how to implement it.

Right now, this is how am making an `Insert` request:

```
/**
 * Inserts a new {@code ToDo}.
 */
@ApiMethod(
        name = "insert",
        path = "todo",
        httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.POST)
public ToDo insert(ToDo todo) {

    ofy().save().entity(todo).now();
    logger.info("Created ToDo with ID: " + todo.getEmpId());

    return ofy().load().entity(todo).now();
}
```

When someone stores a todo, it should be available only to them.My app authenticates users using `Google+` login

Answer (score 1):

In order to user the user API just add a parameter of the type `com.google.appengine.api.users.User` , and GAE will inject the corresponding user fetched using the users API (or null if not logged in ) you can read more info about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/auth).

It seems however that what you actually want to do is implement a multitenancy app using different namespaces for different users, check [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/multitenancy/multitenancy) which explains how to set a namespace for each user and therefore prevent users from accesing each other's data.

Comment: I think am not being clear enough.What I want is basically what every other app does.You log in, save todos, view them or delete them.I log in and do the same.I don't have to know what you are doing, and you don't need to know what am doing.What I have now is my app makes request to app engine and fetches all the data there through the API methods i exposed

Comment: that's multitenancy, please look into the link i sent on my answer. If you are not confortable with using namespaces you'll just have to add an owner parameter to your todo items and query using that.

Comment: Hi  @jirungaray, I have given this a fair amount of research and multitenancy is definitely what am looking for.Problem is, the documentation only describes how to implement it in Servlets, nothing there or anywhere else on how to use it with cloud endpoint APIs.